# What is difference between these regexes

Tags: regex

Given this input:

```
ESAS NO     :2005-238
```

These 2 regex doesn't match:

```
esas\s+(no)?\s*:([^\w]+)
esas\s+(no)?\s*:([\W]+)
```

But this one matches:

```
esas\s+(no)?\s*:([^a-zA-Z]+)
```

I thought all of above would/should behave equally, but they aren't. What is the difference between those?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\w` matches any alphanumeric character, *including digits*, i.e., it's roughly the same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and/but may depend on the locale.

Comment: +1, but depending on the regex engine, it may match much more than that. In .NET, for example, `\w` matches all Unicode letters, digits and "connecting punctuation".

Comment: @TimPietzcker, that's why I said "roughly the same as".

Answer (score 1):

Look at the description for `\w`:

```
\w    A word character is a character from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character.
\W    The negated version of \w
```

That means by using `\W` or `[^\w]` you explicitly exclude `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Note that `0-9` is excluded from the matching set, but in your string there are digits you need to match.

Comment: What you quoted is not a helpful description IMO. Your own words do a better job of explaining the difference.